# Reuse sources which already have CMakelists everywhere to create a nother CMake project with them

Tags: cmake, qmake

Note: I am terribly new at CMake.

So I have this project's source repo in my hands, which is already armed with CMakeLists everywhere. I need to reuse the sources for a different aim (but still perform the functionality that this source offers). So it's a different way of compiling things, and I need new CMakeLists everywhere. Basically, the environment I have to integrate that stuff into has its own CMake functions, but the source repo already has some which do not seem to do exactly what I need.

What's the best practice here?

The thing is, when I compare with QMake for Qt, for example, I can list the sources in a different place than in the source folder itself (i.e. the .pro may be located elsewhere), so I can have multiple projects using the same source folder (or even, in Git linguo, the same source repo as submodule) in a different way (compiling it differently). But CMake requires to add files inside every source subfolder ...

Comment: You are mistaken that CMake has any such requirements about having a file in every source folder.

Comment: Oh really! Well that is the case in the project I was told to work off of anyhow, so I have to make do with that.